# What does global scope means in client-side Javascript that runs inside web browser

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

According to MDN:

> In client-side JavaScript, the global scope is generally the web page inside which all the code is being executed.

Now because of hoisting when HTML web page loads(that is the start of the global scope), all global variable should be created and initialized to `undefined`.

To test this I created three files:

test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src = "test2.js"></script>
<script src = "test1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test2.js:

```
alert(g); // ReferenceError: g is not defined (web browser console)
function increment()
{
    g = g + 1;
}
```

test1.js:

```
var g = 1;
increment();
alert(g); // alert's 2
```

why `alert(g)` in test2.js results in a `ReferenceError`? why `g`'s declaration isn't hoisted up to the start of the global scope?

I think `g`'s declaration is not hoisted up to the start of the global scope because if it was, `g` must have been created and initialized to `undefined` when test.html loads and thus `alert(g)` in test2.js should alert undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with scope. It is about timing.

Each `<script>` will be executed as it is parsed.

Variables defined in subsequent scripts, while they will appear in the same scope, are not hoisted so they exist while a previous script runs.

Comment: thanks for response. so global variable are hoisted up to top of the <script>in which they are defined ? (not to the start of global scope)

Comment: @pixo The files are parsed in the order they show up. It does not do it partially, has nothing to do with hoisting.

Comment: @epascarello thanks. so `g`s declaration is only seen when browser parses the second `<script>` (the <script> that `g` is defined in). then when `g`s declaration is seen by browser every script in the web page can use it.

Answer (score -2):

All variable inside  tags or script files (XXX.js) is global if the variable is not scope in functions. you don't add global words or anything else when you define a variable if you want the variable be global.

In this case you need first define variable after that call them , in JS language, machine first parsing all code line by line and when finished first Js file go to parsing to another file . when compiler look at test2.js does not find any variable because the variable will be defined after parsing of test2.js complated in test1.js

Comment: @epascarello this's completed.